# Scala - Calculate using last elements for the arrays

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with below structure

```
ID:string
Amt:long
Col:array
    element:struct
        Seq:int
        Pct:double
        Sh:double
```

Dataframe output

```
+----+-------+------------------------------------------+
|ID  |Amt    |col                                       |
+----+-------+------------------------------------------+
|ABC |23077  |[[1, 1.5, 1, 10000], [2, 1.2, 2.5,40000]] |
+------------+------------------------------------------+
```

I need to to the following calculation
Last element of the first arrary will be same 10000.
For the next array I need to minus it with the value from first (40000-10000) and get output as 30000

```
Expected output
+----+-------+-------------------------------------------+
|ID  |Amt    |col1                                       |
+----+---------------------------------------------------+
|ABC |23077  |[[1, 1.5, 1, 10000], [2, 1.2, 2.5, 30000]] |
+----+-------+-------------------------------------------+
```

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `transform` and compare the Amt with the previous entry:

```
val df2 = df.withColumn(
    "col", 
    expr("""
        transform(
            col, 
            (x, i) -> struct(
                x.Seq as Seq, x.Pct as Pct, x.Sh as Sh, 
                case when i=0 then x.Amt else x.Amt - col[i-1].Amt end as Amt
            )
        )
    """)
)

df2.show(false)
+-----+---+--------------------------------------------+
|Amt  |ID |col                                         |
+-----+---+--------------------------------------------+
|23077|ABC|[[1, 1.5, 1.0, 10000], [2, 1.2, 2.5, 30000]]|
+-----+---+--------------------------------------------+
```